# Tinymce - insert html code

Tags: php, javascript, html, insert, tinymce

I would appreciate if there is someone who can help me solve this problem, I've been trying to resolve it for few days, but with no success.
I made custom button that inserts image into code, and here is textual version:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<br><img alt=$img_title src=$link/img/sadrzaj/$file\>');">Insert Image</a>
```

Problem is that I'm not allowed to use quotes so I have to use alt=Some_value and quotes are added automaticly.
Problem comes when i enter value with space: alt=Some value and then only "Some" is entered while everything after whitespace is ignored. For src attribute it's ok because it cant contain whitespaces, but for image description it would be very useful.
I can format string and put _ instead of whitespace but that's not solution.

Any help, please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a backslash (`\`) before the quotes you want to include.

```
<a href="javascript:;" 
  onmousedown="tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<br>
  <img alt=\'$img_title\' src=\'$link/img/sadrzaj/$file\' />');">Insert Image</a>
```

This will allow you to include the script and the quotes without it breaking on you.

The backslash just says to the code, "Don't stop here, this quote does not signal the end of the code line. Just include this in the display output. Thanks."

Note that you will have to use single quotes (`'`) around the `IMG` attributes.

(Another thing: In XHTML, when self-closing a tag like `IMG`, you use the slash (`/`) and not the backslash.)

Comment: This doesnt work but still you helped me to find solution. I tried with single qoutes and backslash and it worked.
If printing in php it should look like this:
alt=\\'$naslov_slike\\'

Comment: Cool, have fixed up to account for the single-quotes working and not double-quotes.

Answer (score 6):

It might be better to make your code more readable (if you ever need to go back and change things), you could just make the onmousedown call a function:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="addImage()">Insert Image</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addImage(){
 tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<br>
  <img alt="$img_title" src="$link/img/sadrzaj/$file" />');
}
</script>
```