# TinyMCE - inserting hidden INPUT tag

Tags: tinymce

Really need some help here...I have the following code:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="addMailMergeItem()">[Insert Item]</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
function addMailMergeItem(){
  tinymce.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<input type=\'hidden\' name=\'a\' value=\'1\'/>');
}
</script>
```

However on clicking [Insert Item] the HTML added is:

```
<P><INPUT value=1 type=hidden name=a></P>
```

which makes the input field visible as the 'hidden' type is not recognised!

How can I amend the execCommand() line to achieve what I am after..?

Tamim.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function addMailMergeItem(){
  tinymce.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<input type="hidden" name="a" value="1"/>');
}
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It totally ignores the double-quote. The HTML spat out is: <P><INPUT value=1 type=hidden name=a></P> - and thus the input field is visible,

Comment: ok, let's give it one more go, this time add the slash in front of the double quotes (like this: tinymce.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"a\" value=\"1\"/>');

Comment: no that doesn't work either. HTML output exactly the same as above. Thank you for trying, Andrei.

Comment: take a look at some other questions that have been answered here about the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514005/tinymce-insert-html-code

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Andrei Gs answer you should check if valid_elements contains the given attributes for input elements. Otherwise the attribute gets stripped by the tinymce cleanup function.

Answer (score 0):

Very much looks like this is a browser issue. Can confirm that the problem is manifest in ie8:

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=24899

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=6994

http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8499

Answer (score 0):

I didn't dig much into this, i found the answer and worked for me as a charm:

```
cleanup_on_startup: false,
trim_span_elements: false,
verify_html: false,
cleanup: false,
convert_urls: false,
```